# How to Buy with WBNB instead of BNB

Tags: web3js, web3.py

I wish to buy with WBNB. Instead of BNB on selling to WBNB I use swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens and it works fine.

How can I buy with WBNB?
Here is a TX hash with O BNB value sent
0xc9b4890921a1ab515d1c4d268bcf61ce7836af97ba4683007e9f4d6074d1a386

```
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        0, # Set to 0 or specify min number of tokens - setting to 0 just buys X amount of token at its current price for whatever BNB specified
        [spend,tokenToBuy],
        walletAddress,
        (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)
        ).buildTransaction({
        'from': walletAddress,
        'value': web3.toWei(float(snipeBNBAmount), 'ether'), #This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
        'gas': gasAmount,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
        })``
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I fully understand your question, but when you use the swapExactETHForTokens function you are actually buying using wBNB, not BNB. If the router notices that you do not have enough wBNB for buying said token, it will use the deposit function of the wBNB smart contract. And so even if you have BNB and not wBNB, you are always paying with wBNB. You can see that in the router contract:

https://www.bscscan.com/address/0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e#code

If you wish to obtain wBNB from your BNB I would recommend you using the deposit function from the wBNB smart contract, you can find it in the following link.

https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c#writeContract

Best wishes and good luck in whichever project you are working on